# MAC OS X Custom Application Keeping Bouncing in the Dock

Tags: java, python, macos

First of all, thank you for taking the time to read this. I am new to developing applications for the Mac and I am having some problems. My application works fine, and that is not the focus of my question. Rather, I have a python program which essentially does this:

```
for i in values: 
    os.system(java program_and_options[i])
```

However, every time my program executes the java program, a java window is created in my dock (with an annoying animation) and most importantly steals the focus of my mouse and keyboard. Then it goes away a second later, to be replaced by another Java instance. This means that my batch program cannot be used while I am interacting with my Mac, because I get a hiccup every second or more often and cannot get anything done. My problem is that the act of displaying something in the dock takes my focus, and I would like it not to. Is there a setting on OS X to never display something in the dock (such as Java or python)?

Is there a Mac setting or term that I should use to properly describe this problem I am having? I completely lack the vocabulary to describe this problem and I hope I make sense. I appreciate any help.

I am running Mac OS X, Version 10.5.7 with a 1.66 GHz Intel Core Due, 2 GB memory, Macintosh HD. I am running Python 2.5.1, java version "1.5.0_16" Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_16-b06-284) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_16-133, mixed mode, sharing).

Thanks again,

-Brian J. Stinar-

Answer (score 1):

Does running Java with headless mode = true fix it?

http://zzamboni.org/brt/2007/12/07/disable-dock-icon-for-java-programs-in-mac-osx-howto/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no way to disable the annoying double Java bounce without making your Java application a first class citizen on Mac OS X (much like NetBeans, or Eclipse). As for making certain programs not show in the dock, there are .plist modifications that can be made so that the program does not show up in the dock. See http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20010701191518268

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to write a Java application which doesn't display in the Dock... in fact, it's the default. If your application *is* showing up, it must be doing something which triggers window server access -- your best bet is to try and figure out what that is.